# How to login to Macbook with unmounted volumes?

Tags: macos, boot, macos-catalina

Yesterday I did the latest Catalina update, which lead to the touch id not working anymore. Then today after I installed Flutter and AndroidStudio, I tried to launch the MacBook in Security mode to reenable the touch id.

However, now I cannot login again with my right password. When I am using CMD+R, I need two attempts to get to the Utilities menu. When I use the terminal to resetpassword, I have to login with my Apple ID and then it says: "succesful". Yet, I am not asked to enter a new password and after a restart nothing changes.

I now checked Disk Utility and I realized that both Macintosh Data and Macintosh HD are not mounted. When I try to mount them, I get the error(com.apple.DiskManagement.disenter-Error 49229.)

If I try to mount the Countainer disk2 (in which both volumes are inside, I get the error "Some APFS cryptographic state information was unexpectedly unavailable (-69461).

Also, when I click on Startup disk, MacOs shows no options. Unfortunately, I am unsure whether this issue was caused because of the Catalina update, or because I accidentily deleted one .bash_App.... file I accidentily deleted this file when I wanted to create my flutter path. I am not sure how the full title of the file was but can the deletion of one file cause this issue?

Since I have very important files on this macbook, I would appreciate if there is any method to rescue these files or in best case get access back to the system. Thank you for your help!